# Polyline color change HERE maps

Tags: javascript, maps, heremaps, here-maps-rest

I am trying to change the color of the roads by pulling the properties from base map and for water or landuse.park the "**polygons.color**" works perfectly fine but when I try to do roads which are polylines, I get an error of **undefined reading "color"**. I did try to change "**polygons.color**" to "**polylines.color**" but still the same error.

```js
const parkConfig = parkStyle.extractConfig(['roads.highway'], true, true);

parkConfig.layers.roads.highway.polygons.color = '#2ba815';
```